# Real Time data processing without delay

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, real-time-data

Guys we have a problem to solve We are running our server on AWS and database is MySQL Amazon Aurora. Our data comes in one table via API from mobile devices and goes to another table via AWS pipelines so the problem is that we want to apply some aggregation on real time data while inserting to second table. Remembered data is constantly coming up in the first table.

**Example:**

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

**Problem:**

Want to apply aggregation (mostly sum operations on clicks, impressions columns etc) on real time data and store in second table so we can display summarize data to our users without much delay, please ask me if you don't understand the problem.

**What we want:**

How can we apply aggregation and process real time data while data is coming constantly, We want to know the best approach to solve this problem.

Comment: Perhaps https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/ is a good solution for you.

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws